# Missing $ in citation

Tags: bibtex, citing, texmaker

I'm using jabref and the apacite package to create my citation. In my term paper I'd like to cite a Eurostat website, and attempt to add this as a "misc" citation, which I will put in in below. However, when running the code I get the error `"! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ ...plained/index.php?title=Asylum_statistics}`. I've attempted to put in `$` at the point it refers to and around all the numbers in the citation, but the same error still persist. I've also attempted to create the citation simply in notepad rather than using jabref, without any luck. Any clue as to how to solve this?
Citation:

```
@Misc{EuroStatImg,
author = {Eurostat},
title  = {{Number of asylum applicants (non-EU-27 citizens), EU-27, 2008-2019}},
url    = {{https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=Asylum_statistics}},
}
```

Code in latex (TexMaker)

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \title{The EU's common asylum policy, and the end of the Dublin Agreement}
    \author{Put in Candidat Number}
    \usepackage{apacite}
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \newpage
    Lorem Ipsum \cite{EuroStatImg}

    \bibliography{KilderTermPaper}
    \bibliographystyle{apacite}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\usepackage{url}`.

Comment: Thank you! That solved it!

Comment: Unrelated: why is there an extra set of `{}`on the URL data?

Comment: Great question! I have no idea, so I just removed them. Thank you for pointing it out!